# ExtJS RTL: The Column headers row is not horizontally synched with the table

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Here is my grid.
[image]

Here is my Extjs Version:

[image]

Extjs team stated on [this post](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/extjs-build/release-notes.html) that they have resolved bug 11245.
But I am seeing this bug on my machine.

Is there a way to see how they fixed the bug?

Is there any work around I can apply to sync the header and the lines?